# Real time object detection python

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a real time object detection project in python (mostly only detecting one full body)
that I would like to implement to an android phone.

I have tried opencv with haar cascade with its default "upper body" template data, however it's not detecting it as accurately as I'd like it to be. Also I would prefer something where I can set it only to detect one person wearing a specific clothing.

Are there any suggestions to how I should start this as a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefer `YOLOv3` object detection system which could train itself from a certain `dataset`. With this methodology you can create your own `dataset` in your case it's a person wearing a specific clothing.

First understand the logic behind why you should use `YOLOv3` instead of `OpenCv`.

I could recommend you to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eIBisqx9_g this youtube video than watch this video to do your object detection system https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZ8HxF02KNw.

After these steps you should search about training your own dataset. Good luck...